# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using JQuery:

```
$('#myDiv').load('myApp/url',function(){ });
```

and it's giving No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource By chrome, and firefox so far , any straight forward answer on how to fix this . I don't have control over server to make any configurations and I'm using PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: *"I don't have control over server to make any configurations and I'm using PHP"* **then you can't fix it.**

Comment: Oh my ! Thanks for the response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a CORS issue (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), you are trying to request content via ajax from two different domains. Unless the domain from where you want to grab the data has properly set the CORS headers, browsers will cancel the request right away.

This occurs due to the communication between two different domains. The domain that will server your data, should have some headers set, this headers act as permissions, they tell which domains are allowed to ask for data from it, and which verbs/methods are allowed.

You can read more about this [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/?redirect_from_locale=es) and [here](http://enable-cors.org/)

Comment: yeah i read html5rocks article , but still i'm confused what's really happening , can you give me an example on how this problem occurs . Thank you so much !

Comment: This issue occurs because ajax calls from one domain to another is a form of Cross-site Scripting which is a security hole. Browsers stop these requests in order to protect their users.  However, CORS is a technique for getting around this.  The domain from which you are requesting data has to tell the browser that your domain is ok with them and should allow the request.

Since you say you can't control the remote server, an alternative way to get around this is jsonp...

Comment: Needed this explanation , Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

No, there won't be a straight forward answer to this because it will depend entirely on your system/server setup, and what you have access to.  Here's what you need to know.

In the beginning -- AJAX requests had a very strict "same origin" policy.  This meant if you made an ajax request FROM a website with the domain `example.com`, you could only make a request **to** a URL that was on `example.com`.

In more recent years browsers have loosened up on this.  If the server that you're making a request **to** has an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and that header includes the URL/domain of the server you're making the request **from**, then the request will be allowed.  Similar [question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work).

So, **how** you set this header depends on the server you're making a request to.  If you have control over this server, start your Googling there.

If you don't have control over this server, you need to make a request to `php` page on **your** server, and this PHP page should make a `curl` request to the server that had the information you don't.  A `curl` request, happening outside the browser, isn't subject to the same cross domain issues.

Answer (score -2):

The easy way is to do this by hand:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = uri;
script.id = 'scriptid';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

It may be some browser compatibility issues, but you get the power of CORS with no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error